# How to unpack a python object to transform the contents into another object/text?

Tags: python-3.x

I want to combine SVG objects from files with new elements I need to create (headers and lines)

I am using SVGWRITE to create new objects.
https://github.com/mozman/svgwrite

And SVGUTILS to grab SVG files from disk/web and combine.
https://svgwrite.readthedocs.io/en/master/classes/svg.html

I want to pass an SVG object created by SVGWRITE to SVGUTILS.

SVGUTILS can take an XML SVG object.

```
svgutils.transform.fromstring(text)
```

SVGWRITE creates python objects

```
class svgwrite.container.SVG(insert=None, size=None, **extra)
```

or

```
class svgwrite.drawing.Drawing(filename=u'noname.svg', size=(u'100%', u'100%'), **extra)
```

How can I transform an SVGWRITE object into text that SVGUTILS can accept? Or what is a strategy for figuring out how to unpack an SVGWRITE object to transform it into a SVGUTILS object or text?

Answer (score 1):

It seems like the easiest interface between the two libraries is through files. So if you start out with svgwrite object you can open the file using svgutils in the following way.

```
import svgutils.transform as sg
import svgwrite

dwg = svgwrite.Drawing('test.svg', profile='tiny')
dwc.save()

usig_svgutils = sg.fromfile('test.svg')
```

Comment: @kalmdown, perhaps there is a low level way of doing it another way. But I wouldn't bet on it. But otherwise feel free to accept my answer :)